# Proving a set releation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Theorem:Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets, $A\setminus B ⊆C$, and $x $ is anything at all. If $x ∈ A\setminus C$ then $x ∈ B$.

Proof:
Suppose $x ∈ A\setminus C$.This means that $x ∈ A$ and  $x\notin C$.Suppose $x \not\in B$. Then $x ∈ A\setminus B$, so since $A\setminus B ⊆C,x ∈C$. But this contradicts the fact that $x \notin C$. Therefore $x ∈ B$. Thus, if $x ∈ A\setminus C$ then $x ∈ B$.

What i did not understand about this proof is that how did they get from  $x ∈ A\setminus C$ to $x ∈ A\setminus B$. Could anyone explain the proof to me. Thanks

Comment: if x is excluded from C then certainly it is excluded from B, since B is contained in C

Comment: $x$ is not "anything at all" (it does not make much sense). Every element of a set is a set

Comment: But how do we know that B is contained in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption of $x\in A\setminus C$ and $x\notin B$ we have

- $x\in A$
- $x\notin B$

(We also have that $x\notin C$, but it doesn't matter now).

The elements of $A\setminus B$ are precisely the elements of $A$ that are not in $B$. So we conclude that $x\in A\setminus B$

Answer (score 0):

In the proof you give, "Suppose $x\notin B$" starts a proof by contradiction.  We already have that $x\in A$.  So now (within the proof by contradiction), we have $x\in A\backslash B$

Comment: Im thinking whether it is possible to prove by some other way, such as by the Contrapositive method

Comment: To prove by contrapositive, you would assume $x\notin B$ and show that $x\notin A\backslash C$.  $x\notin A\backslash C$ is equivalent to $x\notin A$ or $x\in C$.  If $x\notin A$, you're done; and if $x\in A$, then since $x\notin B$ you have $x \in A\backslash B\subseteq C$.